# Loading Dynamics CDM with Azure Data Factory (@entityReference)

Tags: dynamics-crm, azure-data-factory, entityreference, common-data-service

Using Azure Data Factory to Sink to Dynamics Common Data Model.

**Source:**

```
Col1: CustomerName
Col2: CustomerGroup
```

**Destination - CDM**

```
Col1: CustomerName
Col2: CustomerGroup (this is Lookup Column in Dynamics)
```

Fails when mapping in ADF is:

```
Src.CustomerName -----------> Dst.CustomerName
Src.CustomerGroup ----------> Dst.CustomerGroup
```

followed the docs @ https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/data-factory/connector-dynamics-crm-office-365#writing-data-to-a-lookup-field and updated the mappings as below:

```
Src.CustomerName -----------> Dst.CustomerName
Src.CustomerGroup ----------> Dst.CustomerGroup**@EntityReference**
```

This works, but didn't populate the column **Dst.CustomerGroup** with the value

Any Clues..

Answer (score 0):

As we know the sink column is a virtual column representing the entity reference. A Lookup may refer to more than one entity type.

As the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/data-factory/connector-dynamics-crm-office-365#writing-data-to-a-lookup-field) said:
What about adding an additional column in the copy activity source?

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to use the same approach inside dataflow in adf?